# laravel livewire Save file using file name

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to save uploaded pdf files but the pdf file name changes on the storage link. is there any way to retain the original file name when saving?

```
public $code, $pdfs;

public function mount(Applicant $applicant)
    {
        $this->code = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 5)), 0, 3).Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', now())->format('md').rand(100, 999);
    }

public function submit(Request $request)
    {
 
        $this->validate([
             'pdfs.*' => 'mimes:pdf',
          ]);

        $filenames = collect($this->tests)->map->store($this->code.'/', 'public');
        return redirect()->route('careers.vacant');
    }
```

here's my blade

```
<form wire:submit.prevent="submit" class="pt-3" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="form-label required" for="code" >Application {{ trans('fields.code') }}</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="code" id="code" wire:model.defer="code" >
        <div class="validation-message">
            {{ $errors->first('code') }}
        </div>
        <div class="help-block">
            {{ trans('fields.code_helper') }}
        </div>
    </div>

<input type="file" name="pdf" id="pdf" wire:model="pdfs" multiple >
    <div wire:loading wire:target="pdfs">Uploading...</div>
    @error('pdfs.*') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror

<div class="form-group">
        <button class="mr-2 btn btn-indigo" type="submit">
            {{ trans('global.submit') }}
        </button>
        <a href="{{ route('admin.applicants.index') }}" class="btn btn-secondary">
            {{ trans('global.cancel') }}
        </a>
    </div>
</form>
```

I need to save the pdfs like this:

```
$filenames = collect($this->tests)->map->store($this->code.'/'.pdfFileName, 'public');
```

EDIT:

```
foreach ($this->tests as $file) {
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->store('moca/'.$this->code.'/'.$name, 'public');

        }
```

I tried this code but in the path `$name` becomes a folder instead of becoming the name of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The livewire uploaded file object is of type **TemporaryUploadedFile** which extends the **UploadedFile** class. So you can use all the Laravel's **UploadedFile** methods.

First you get the filename like so:

```
$filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
```

Then you save the file using this name.

```
$path = $file->storeAs('destination/folder', $filename ,'public');
```

If everything works the file should be saved in: **storage/app/public/destination/folder/$filename**

The **$path** variable will be equal to: **destination/folder/$filename** or **false** if operation failed.
For this to work the **public disk** should be configured correctly.
[Laravel docs - The Public Disk](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#the-public-disk).

By default, the public disk uses the local driver and stores its files in **storage/app/public**.

To make these files accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from **public/storage** to **storage/app/public**.

To access the file via web you will have to use the follwoing code:

```
$web_url = asset('storage/'.$path);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

`$request->file('pdf')->getClientOriginalName()` will return the original name of file

Comment: it gives me error when multiple pdfs are uploaded

Comment: @KrutSednar Just foreach files and you can handle every file saparately. Something like `foreach ($request->file('pdfs') as $pdf) { $fileName = $pdf->getClientOriginalName();  }`

Comment: I tried 
```
foreach ($this->tests as $file) {
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->store('moca/'.$this->code.'/'.$name, 'public');

        }
```

but in the path >$name becomes a folder instead of becoming the name of the file

Comment: @KrutSednar Try using method `putFileAs` to save file with specify name.  Like this `Storage::putFileAs($path, $file, $specifyFileName);`